# Assign row and column to points in a dataframe by its coordinates

Tags: r

A list of points with x and y coordinates form a square lattice, how do I know to which row and column of each lattice each point corresponds?

To take an easy example, I would start with a dataframe like this.

```
x_coordinates <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3)
y_coordinates <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2)
df_points <- data.frame(x_coordinates, y_coordinates)
df_points$row <- NA
df_points$column <- NA
df_points

x_coordinates y_coordinates column row
1             1             1  NA     NA
2             2             1  NA     NA
3             3             1  NA     NA
4             1             2  NA     NA
5             2             2  NA     NA
6             3             2  NA     NA
```

Where rows and columns are still unknown. The obvious answer to this example would be:

```
df_points$column <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3)
df_points$row <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2)
df_points

x_coordinates y_coordinates column row
1             1             1   1      1
2             2             1   2      1
3             3             1   3      1
4             1             2   1      2
5             2             2   2      2
6             3             2   3      2
```

But I would need to apply it to larger and more complex examples such as:

```
df_points$x_coordinates <- c(10,30,50,10,30,50)
df_points$y_coordinates <- c(15,15,15,20,20,20)
df_points
              x_coordinates y_coordinates column row
1             10             15           1      1
2             30             15           2      1
3             50             15           3      1
4             10             20           1      2
5             30             20           2      2
6             50             20           3      2
```

Or even and example where rows and columns are not aligned:

```
  x_coordinates y_coordinates column   row
1             10             15   1      1
2             30             16   2      1
3             50             17   3      1
4             12             20   1      2
5             32             21   2      2
6             52             22   3      2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using library(raster)

```
find_rowcol = function(df, nrow=2) {
  df[,2] = -df[,2]
  e <- extent(as.matrix(df[,1:2]))
  r <- raster(e, ncol=NROW(df)/nrow, nrow=nrow)
  rowColFromCell(r, cellFromXY(r, df[,1:2]))
}

df_points$x_coordinates <- c(10,30,50,12,32,52)
df_points$y_coordinates <- c(15,16,17,20,21,22)
find_rowcol(df_points)
#      row col
# [1,]   1   1
# [2,]   1   2
# [3,]   1   3
# [4,]   2   1
# [5,]   2   2
# [6,]   2   3
```

Answer (score 2):

A variation on dww's answer

Example data

```
x <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3)
y <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2)
xy <- cbind(x=x, y=y)
```

Solution

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(xy, type="xyz")    
rc <- rowColFromCell(r, cellFromXY(r, xy))
colnames(rc) <- c("row", "col")
data.frame(xy, rc)

  x y row col
1 1 1   2   1
2 2 1   2   2
3 3 1   2   3
4 1 2   1   1
5 2 2   1   2
6 3 2   1   3
```

But note that the row counting is from top to bottom.

Comment: "note that the row counting is from top to bottom" - that's why I included line`df[,2] = -df[,2]` in my answer.  Can do the same here.

Comment: I really like the `type = "xyz"` approach.  I'm gradually trying to transition to terra and answers like this are really informative to help learn it (+1).  However, this method does not work "out of the box" for OPs final example in which points are not precisely aligned on grid.  I'm not sure if there is an easy way to choose the correct resolution automatically in this case, so perhaps user also needs to specify nrow/ncol?